# Qt - cross platform behaviour

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface, cross-platform

I am trying to deploy a cross platform Qt application written in c++. It works fine on my Ubuntu Linux but when I run it on Windows the application's main window's position gets set on the very top left point of the screen with the upper frame (that holds the minimize, maximize, close buttons) **missing**.

That is it until i resize the main window (in this case making the width smaller from the right). When this happens the upper frame and the control buttons appear as in the visualization I provided.

[image: See here.]

Note: I've removed all widgets on the app so they do not аppear as a distraction.

Note2: It appears the maximize button is disabled, which is not the case inside Ubuntu. I have not set any window flags.

How do i visualize the upper frame at the very start of the application without the need to resize the window. I understand its an OS specific behaviour. Setting the main window's geometry with a starting point with a higher y value does NOT help. It still pops at the very top left of the screen.

Comment: Do you use `QWidget::showMaximized()` function? How do you set the geometry of your window?

Comment: @vahancho No, I do not use showMaximized(). In the MainWindow constructor at the end 
`this->setGeometry(0, 0, 1336, 600);`.
I know x:0 and y:0 is the top left point and thats Ok. Its just the frame that does not appear inside Windows. In ubuntu the frame is there.

Comment: I suspect, that `setGeometry()` function doesn't consider the title bar and set's position of the **client** part of your main window. That's why your main window's title bar goes off screen. I would try to use `QWidget::showMaximized()` if it does what you need.

Comment: @vahancho showMaximized() does the thing but i must not start the app in maximized mode. Its a huge workaround to a small problem

Answer (score 0):

try to use [QWidget::move](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#move-1) to set the Window position after `setGeometry`.

> If the widget is a window, the position is that of the widget on the
>   desktop, including its frame.

Answer (score 0):

You ask a question about cross-platform UI code, and then you don't show the full code. Please show the full code.

The one line of code you do show does something in the wrong way: if you want to maximize a window, call the appropriate function, instead of setting its absolute size that you think shows the window maximized. Windows, their decorations and their placement are very very platform specific, and you should prefer their cross-platform abstractions over trying to do them yourself.

Concretely: the window positioning handles the decorations (title bar) differently on Windows and on Ubuntu. There is absolutely nothing you can do about it except not position your windows absolutely like this.

Answer (score 0):

> In the MainWindow constructor at the end `this->setGeometry(0, 0, 1336, 600);`

That's the problem. `setGeometry` deals with the geometry of the client area. This is [well documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#window-geometry). You should use `move` to change the position of the widget frame. To set the size of the frame requires the knowledge of the frame's incremental width and height:

```
bool setWidgetFrameGeometry(QWidget *w, const QRect &r) {
  auto frame = w->frameGeometry().size();
  auto client = w->size();
  auto delta = frame - client;
  auto maxDelta = 128;
  if (delta.width() > 0 && delta.width() < maxDelta 
      && delta.height() > 0 && delta.height() < maxDelta) {
    w->move(r.topLeft());
    w->resize(r.size() - delta);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The call may need to be deferred to when the event loop had a chance to run:

```
auto setter = [this]{ return setWidgetFrameGeometry(this, {0,0,1336,600}); };
if (!setter())
  QTimer::singleShot(0, this, setter);
```